# How to prevent e.preventDefault() called infinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="menu">Choose option:</label>
  <select name="menu" id="menu">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="additional_field" name="custId" value="3487">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" action="">
  <label for="additional_field">Additional field:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="additional_field" name="additional_field" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have 2 forms:

- form1 is the main-form
- form2 is hidden popup modal

The rule:

- if visitor choose option1 at form1, just continue the form submission
  as usual. nothing to do here.
- If visitor choose option2 at form1, stop form1 submission and show
  form2 modal because we need additional field. after visitor fill and
  click form2 submit. we will continue the submission of form1
  including the additional_field in form2 as the additional parameter
  in form1.
- If visitor choose option2 at form1, the only way to submit form1 is
  when visitor click the submit button on form2.

What is the best way jquery logic to achive this?  How to make sure e.preventDefaut not called twice when submitted from form2?

I have tried this, but failed:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e){

    if( $('#menu').val() == 'option2' ){
        //show modal here
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }

});
$("#form2").submit(function(e){
    var additional_field = $('#additional_field').val();
    $("#form1").append('<input type="hidden" name="additional_field" value="' + additional_field + '" />')
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `form2Filled` is a flag which is initialized with `false`. When Form 1 gets submitted :

1. If option 1 is selected, if condition produces false, and form gets submitted.
2. If option 2 is selected, if condition produces `true`, and modal gets displayed.
3. When Form 2 gets filled, `form2Filled` becomes `true`, and submits form 1, if condition produces false, and form 1 gets submitted.

```js
 var form2Filled = false;
 var form1 = $("#form1");

 form1.submit(function(e) {
   if (!form2Filled && $('#menu').val() == 'option2') {
      //show modal here
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
 });


 $("#form2").submit(function(e) {
   form2Filled = true;
   var additional_field = $('#additional_field').val();
   form1.append('<input type="hidden" name="additional_field" value="' + additional_field + '" />')
   form1.submit();
 });
```

**ALSO** : Instead of using `$("#form1")` again and again, you can assign the retrieved element to a variable, and use that variable. It improves efficiency and is a good practice. :)

Comment: I cant use this method because there is another event listener for that submit form. so this event listener can either allow or deny the form submission based on if all required fields filled or not. if your version of event listener run first, and form2Filled set to true.and then the other listener deny the form submission because of required field doesnt inputted. so the second time user click submit, your listener will not run, because you already have set form2filled to true.

Comment: @rudyanshah8342 You can try to make some logic like if-else for that... In case that's not possible, can you please share the other event listener as well?